# Sanitize CSS in PHP - Ruby Alternatives an option?

Tags: php, css, ruby-on-rails

We have a requirement to allow users to customise the CSS for a PHP app. In general, only that user will be able to view the custom CSS, but there are cases when other users in their group could also view the CSS, hence the need to ensure that its sanitized.

I am aware that HTMLPurifier and CSSTidy can be used for PHP, but CSSTidy is extremely outdated, and apparently can't handle everything that we need to throw at it.

I havent found any other PHP libs that can do this.

One alternative that I am exploring is taking a ruby library (http://apidock.com/rails/HTML/WhiteListSanitizer/sanitize_css or https://github.com/courtenay/css_file_sanitize/blob/master/lib/css_sanitize.rb) and converting it into php.

Before I go down that route, are there any alternatives to the above? And are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of before using one of the Ruby libs?

Comment: And why exactly HTMLPurifier is not an option here for you? I mean, what's its cons for your case?

Comment: HTMLPurifier on its own does not handle CSS - it depends on CSSTidy. CSSTidy has not been updated for over 5 years - its so far out of date that it doesn't even handle media queries.

Comment: @raina77ow If it hasn't been updated in over 5 years it probably won't support animations either (at a guess).

Comment: Any reason why you cannot port css_sanitize to PHP?

Comment: Facebook used to sanitize CSS. You might look at their older open source projects and see if you can use their CSS sanitizer.

Answer (score 0):

> **Update:**
> After almost eight years later, I wanted to leave a second note
> because my answer start getting downvotes.
>
> I am not dealing with JS/CSS anymore as much as my early career years. I
> did mostly focus on building backend services and tools recent years. So, my knowledge on this subject may be outdated, even if I tried to keep it sharp, which requires discipline and hard work.
>
> Neverthless, nicer tools may exist today other than HtmlPrufier and/or TidyCSS. I am not saying those tools are bad. But community support and active maintenance is important. As a thumb of rule, I am staying away from dead or unmaintained dependencies in my applications.
>
> If PHP is a MUST here to sanitize, I would look into  [Wikimedia's CSS sanitizer](https://github.com/wikimedia/css-sanitizer) first if it works for me. More or less, it's doing the job. Persisting a minified version of given CSS in filesystem, updating as modified on application side also would be a secondary goal for me. A pre-generated version could make my life easier when sending to browser. Any tooling would work there, PHP may just fire a dedicated event for it. Creating sanitized version of CSS may also be a background process candidate rather than generating on demand. Maybe via available tools from other platforms beyond PHP. So there are a lot more options and possibilities out there nowadays.
>
> Hope my explanations shed some light for people trying to achieve something similar.

**Original answer was:**

HTMLPurifier and CSSTidy are right tools. CSSTidy still maintaining by [Cedric Morin](https://github.com/Cerdic) and few other developers [on Github](https://github.com/Cerdic/CSSTidy). Also default CSS level of CSSTidy is **CSS3.0** since April 2012.

You may use that.

Comment: Its just way too heavy to have all that baggage for a single input field. HTMLPurifier is a monster.

Comment: Why not just delete the answer? It's a bad question, off-topic. You can VTC while you're here.

Comment: I am not deleting the answer to be able to demonstrate that the knowledge we gain while writing software may also be get outdated. The question needs to be deleted then. Blindly advocating any tool or library or approach doesn't provide any value. We need think more and try to ask right questions about what we are trying to achieve instead. The "right way" we believe today, could be wrong way in a time window less than a decade.

Comment: That's why requests for libraries or tools are off-topic and shouldn't have been answered in the first place.